# the entries of vector x is not sequential in Chebyshev polynomial in matlab

Tags: matlab

here is the question:
  The degree-n Chebyshev polynomial is defined by Tn(x) = cos[n*arcos(x)]    x is between -1 to 1
these polynomials satisfy T0(x)=1, T1(x)=x, and the recursion relation T(n+1)(x) = 2*x*Tn(x)-T(n-1)(x), n is larger and equal to 1.
Write a function that evaluates all the Chebyshev polynomials of degree less than or equal to N at all the points in the vector x.

here is what I did:

```
c = length(x);
x = x';
T = ones(c,N);
T(:,1) = 1;
T(:,2) = x;

for n = 2:N
    T(:,n+1) = 2*x.*T(:,n)-T(:,n-1);
end
```

I run into problem with entries of x are not sequential between -1 to 1. like x = [-1 0.5 0.2 0.3 1]. The graph of that is weird. I am not sure if I did this right.

Comment: Calculate the corret result and compare it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#First_kind

Answer (score 0):

Try this as your first line of code:

```
x = sort(x);
```

That will put the elements of x in ascending order for you.